# Freeradius ended itself and could not start

Tags: debian, freeradius

I installed Freeradius on Jessie Debian. First it was ok - working. But then, I don't know why it stopped and I can't start it. I tryed reinstall, but there is same problem. Here is status and starting attempt.

```
 radius@debian:~$ /etc/init.d/freeradius status
    ● freeradius.service - LSB: Radius Daemon
       Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/freeradius)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-06-08 11:12:02 BST; 32min ago
```

and after try to start

```
radius@debian:~$ /etc/init.d/freeradius start
[....] Starting freeradius (via systemctl): freeradius.serviceFailed to start freeradius.service: Access denied
 failed!
```

What is more in Ubuntu 12.04 I have same problem.

I used:

```
radius@debian:~$ sudo freeradius -XC
freeradius: FreeRADIUS Version 2.2.5, for host x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, built on Oct 24 2014 at 02:05:28
Copyright (C) 1999-2013 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT.
Starting - reading configuration files ...
including configuration file /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf
Configuration file /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf is globally writable.  Refusing to start due to insecure configuration.
Errors reading or parsing /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf
```

and:

```
radius@debian:~$ sudo freeradius -lstdout -xxx -fC
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Info: freeradius: FreeRADIUS Version 2.2.5, for host x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, built on Oct 24 2014 at 02:05:28
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Debug: Server was built with:
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Debug:   accounting
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Debug:   authentication
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Debug:  WITH_DHCP
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Debug:  WITH_VMPS
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Debug: Server core libs:
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Debug:   ssl: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Info: Copyright (C) 1999-2013 The FreeRADIUS server project and contributors.
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Info: There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Info: PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Info: You may redistribute copies of FreeRADIUS under the terms of the
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Info: GNU General Public License.
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Info: For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYRIGHT.
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Info: Starting - reading configuration files ...
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Debug: including configuration file /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Error: Configuration file /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf is globally writable.  Refusing to start due to insecure configuration.
Fri Jun  9 06:22:07 2017 : Error: Errors reading or parsing /etc/freeradius/radiusd.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Run freeradius with `sudo freeradius -XC`, it'll print out the reason why it cannot start (and then exit).

if `sudo freeradius -XC` reports no errors, it's likely a permissions issue.

Run `sudo freeradius -lstdout -xxx -fc`, FreeRADIUS will then `seuid()/segid()` down to the use configured in `radiusd.conf`.

Comment: So you need to fix the permissions on your configuration files, which I assume you changed, as with the default install they work fine.

Comment: No files in /etc/freeradius should be world writable ``chmod -R g-w /etc/freeradius``

Comment: Ok. I could be issue that I chnged chmod for `radiusd.conf`, `users`, `clients` and `eap`, but this was on `Jessie Debian` and after reinstalling problem was the same. On `Ubuntu` I didn't change anything but there is same problem.

Comment: The `chmod -R g-w /etc/freeradius` command do nothing. Steel there is the same problem.

Comment: Sorry that should have been ``chmod -R o-w /etc/freeradius``